# SQLDelight v1.4 not generating interface

Tags: database, sqldelight

Since [v1.4](https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/releases/tag/1.4.0), SQLDelight generated data class only.
Before, the tool generated interface and a default implementation of this interface.
That was easy to compose objects with associated projections.
Is there any change to get these interface back ?

Comment: Please ask the developer responsible.

Answer (score 1):

see this answer: https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/pull/1698#issuecomment-646306522

essentially to keep the backwards compatibility i would copy and paste the old interfaces yourself. We made this change because that really should have been the original implementation but we needed interfaces to support autovalue, thats no longer the case so if there are still situations where you need interfaces they should probably be user code

Comment: OK thanks for the link. I was looking in doc and release note some informations about this new behavior.